# Android : Right place to keep logic for view visibility

Tags: android, viewmodel

I am implementing a bottom sheet menu. I am using viemodel that is used for databinding in the layout file. The viewmodel has a livedate of type int "selectedOption". I have 5 rows in the menu and each row has an Image. I want to have a logic that this image is visible for row 1 if selectedOption = 1.

What is the right way to implement this logic.
I can have in my layout file:

```
android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(vm.selectedOption) == 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

In this case, which is the right place to define the constants 1, 2 etc. It is already defined in my source file. Can i access it in layout file

Or should I have a livedata for each of that in the viewmodel
like: isRow1Selected

or is there a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be plenty of people with different opinions on what to do here. A big trend in modern mobile development is **driving ui from state**. So you certainly could keep this state of something being selected or not in the view model and have the view respond to changes by observing that state. That is personally what I would do. If you are worried about the 1 and 0 and having janky numbers in your code you could define an enum to hold it and that could by the type of your live data.

ex:

```
enum class Mode(val value: Int) {
    SELECTED(1),
    UNSELECTED(0)
}

viewModel.state.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer { newState ->
     when(newState) {
         Mode.SELECTED -> //Do thing
         Mode.UNSELECTED -> //do thing
     }
})
```